# Equation Parsing Library C++

Tags: c++, parsing, equation

I'm sure there must be something like this somewhere but I can't seem to find anything useful on here or Google. I had hoped Boost might have something but alas not.

What I'm after is a lightweight library that can take a string from the user, for example `"y=2x+3"` and parse it returning an object or function which returns `y` when given `x`.

Can anybody recommend something for this? *(Worst case I could write one myself but no point reinventing the wheel and all.)*

Things which can be assumed if necessary;

- Preset variable names
- Number of variables fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MuParser](http://muparser.sourceforge.net/) is all you ever could wish for. You can even define custom operators, store and evaluate the expressions in binary form, etc... Written in C++, bindings for C and C# (and maybe even other languages).